# Nested selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call the jquery.animate on a nested div. The div structure is something like this

```
<div id="jsPlumb_1_4" class="container">
       <div id="PlanItemPL1" class="PlanItem">
            <div id="window1" class="window">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I am  interested in doing operations such as mousedown event, animate event on the div class window. Can somebody please let me know what selector should I write. Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you want the animation on the inner div or on all the divs?

Comment: on the inner div (div class="window" is which i am interested.)

Comment: @KevinB: I haven't thought of it. I think that normal width and height would work. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, without further specifics in the question, a generic approach:

```
$('#jsPlumb_1_4').on('mousedown', function(e){
    $(this).find('div.window').animate({'width' : '100px'}, 1000);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RYeg/).

In this demonstration I'm binding the `mousedown` event to the `#jsPlumb_1_4` element (the event will propagate from any of its child elements), and triggering the `animate()` on the contained `div.window` element.

To make it a little more interesting, I'm adding a `mouseup` event too, so that on `mousedown` the `div.window` shrinks, and on `mouseup` it grows:

```
$('#jsPlumb_1_4').on('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
    var newWidth = e.type == 'mousedown' ? '50%' : '80%';
    $(this).find('div.window').animate({'width' : newWidth}, 1000);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7RYeg/1/).

`e.type` retrieves the event (`mouseup` or `mousedown`), and the `newWidth` variable is either `50%` or `80%` depending on whether the event is equal to `mousedown` or not.

Comment: I dont know why it is still not working in my code. Is difference CSS for different div can cause the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry? Can you post a representative demo of what you're working with, and what you're trying, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Then I can try and see what's not working.

Comment: You can actually use .mousedown(function(){ $(this).find('div.window').animate({'width' : '100px'}, 1000); }); as well

Comment: @NickG.: So I do not have to specify any selector before the mousedown event?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Here is the jsfiddle link to what I am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/unix_user/CnNXY/2/